# How to store xml content for quick access?

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, bigdata

I'm gettings lots of `xml` file from several content delivery systems. They are not related to each other.

Currently I parse each xml to `java` objects (`@Entity`), and persist them in a `postgres` db.

Problem: when a user wants to access the stored data, the objects are recomposed from the db rows. The root element is always identified by a unique id, and contained data is joined from the different rows.

So in general, I'm repeating the procedure: read xml > decompose to java object > store in db in different tables > (user access) > fetch from db and join the table rows > compose to java object > deliver to user interface by REST or SOAP.

The content is always accessed from the root. Eg a product is accessed by product id. All the sub-content like descriptions, stock, price etc is never accessed directly, but always only by the root product.

Question: wouldn't it be easier to just store the xml `documents` somehow under the unique key, and then the user accesses the content, then only start reading the xml and offer it in a custom format to the user?

If yes: how could I store the content? Of course it's probably not suitable to persist the xml files as `blobs` in the postgres db, but what would be better?

Update:

```
<foo>
  <bars>
    <bar><id>1</id><content>Hello</content></bar>
    <bar><id>2</id><content>Hello2</content></bar>
  <bars>
</foo>

@Entity
public class Foo {
   @Id //auto generated
   private long id;

   @OneToMany
   private List<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
   private int id;
   private String concent;
}
```

Of course the real xml files are much more complex, thus the data will be distributed to many tables and rows. I'm looking now for a way that I don't have to distribute the full xml content so several tables (here one root entry goes to table `foo`, and two entries go to table `bar`). Because when I fetch the content on user request, I would have the unique ID of `foo` and join any content (here only the `bar`) content.

The `bar` content (and any other subcontent) is never accessed without the parent element. So maybe there are better ways to store these kind of data, as the full data is always accessed topdown and always has be be rejoined.

Comment: Would it not be faster if you just save the path to the file into the database with a unique id. Then if an user want to access the content then you could load the xml at that time of need.

Comment: So you're talking about storing the files on a local drive? Well that would be an option, but how might the performance be have several hundred-thousands of local files that should be accessed very quickly? Performance matters as the users requesting the content should not wait longer than necessary.

Comment: Do you need to save the XML in the database? Are you actually using the xml in select queries, for example? Or is the XML only used in the application logic(java)?

Comment: The xml is only used as the "content transfer language". I get the content via xml files, and have to extract some/most of the tags, and then offer the content using a `rest` api (as well as persisting the data soemhow). So I'm acutally not using the xml in any queries. It's just used for transfering the content.

Comment: Maybe also a `nosql` approach is designed for this purpose? (I don't have any experience in nosql).

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't saving the useful information in the database rather than holding onto the raw XML to parse?

Comment: I have xml files coming from different sources. Each has it's own xml structure of course, and must be mapped manually to a rdbm schema so the content can be persisted fully. And on fetch the different rows are rejoined by their primarykeys. What I'm looking for is maybe a better solution, if exists. Because, from the db point of view I never share any rows with multiple root element. Each root element (like a product) has it's own assigned subrows that are joined back on access.

Comment: if you provided an example including DB structure, some data, and some more details on the expected result it would help

Comment: Please have a look at my update if it becomes clearer.